# How do you import a custom polymer element from within a custom element?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to create a custom polymer element that incorporates custom elements from a third party library. My customelement.html file has this in the head section

```
<head>
    <title>orderlist</title>
    <link rel="import" href="packages/widget/components/accordion.html">
    <link rel="import" href="packages/widget/components/collapse.html">
</head>
```

All is well, the editor can find the referenced components.

At runtime, however, Dartium complains that the components can't be found:

```
http://(mylocalhost)/birdweb_web/web/packages/birdweb/packages/widget/components/accordion.html 404 (Not Found)
```

From the URL it appears that Dart wants to find the custom elements in my application's library instead of in the top level packages directory.

How do I use third party polymer elements in my custom element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a known bug (filed) a few days ago
[Issue 13684](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13684&q=import%20polymer%20element%20difficult&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)